# How to calculate the density of states near a point for the given dispersion relation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

The problem's statement is as follows:

> Given that
> $ E(\vec{k}) = ak_x^2  + bk_y^2 + c|k_z|$,
> Calculate the density of states near $(0,0,0)$.

It's easy to do the integration if $E$ is quadratic in all of the components, but in this case there's a linear dependence for the $z$ component. I've tried to calculate it from the definition:

$$ D(E) = \frac{2V}{(2\pi)^3}\int \delta (E(\vec{k}) - E)\, \mathrm{d}\vec{k}$$

But I have no idea how to do the integration through change of coordinates.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

To give you the main ideas of the resolution without giving it away, you can work in several steps:

First, you can do a change of variable for $k_x$, $k_y$ and $k_z$ in order to absorb the constants a,b and c so that the spectrum in the new coordinates is

$E=q_x^2+q_y^2+|q_z|$

then, you can do

-a polar change of variable in the plane qx-qy to reduce the integration since the energy depend on the radius and not the angle

-a change of variable with $q_z$ since $\int_{-a}^a dk f(|k|)=2\int_{0}^a dk f(k)$

Then you can integrate on the radius, reminding that for a function f with zeros at positions $x_i$ we have

$\Delta(f(x))=\sum_i \frac{\delta(x-x_i)}{|f'(x_i)|}$

separating the $q_z$ axis into region where this has no solution and some where it has (depending on the value of E).
Finally the integration on $q_z$ should be doable allowing you to conclude.